# SLURM node with job status "Resources" but also "ReqNodeNotAvail, UnavailableNodes:"

Tags: slurm

is the first time I see this:

```
ST       TIME      NODES NODELIST(REASON)
PD       0:00      1     (Resources)
PD       0:00      1     (ReqNodeNotAvail, UnavailableNodes:node2)
R        2:14      1     node2
```

Is the same job submitted 3 times on the same node. I do not understand why a job is waiting resources while the other job is under "ReqNodeNotAvail". I expect that both had to be under "Resources" or to have a general problem with all jobs. Restarting the server nothing change.

Thanks in advance for the help.